# Why behavior of anchor tag and button is different?

Tags: html, css

When using anchor tag the dropdown menu is positioned below the button but while using a button it is over the menu

[Anchor Tag implementation](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RjErdj)

```
<div class="menubar">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">File 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">New</a>
      <a href="#">Open</a>
      <a href="#">Save</a>    </div>
  </div>
  <a>Edit</a> 
  <a>Tools</a>   
</div>
```

[Button implementation](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gXZPVK)

```
  <div class="menubar">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">File 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <button>New</button> 
      <button>Open</button>
      <button>Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button>Edit</button> 
  <button>Tools</button>   
</div>
```

Comment: In bootstrap4 it's supposed to be through anchor tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The float in the menubar button is causing the issue.

Removing the float corrects the issue, without having an affect on the layout.

The Anchor tag implementation didn't suffer from the same issue, because the "File" item has a button element rather than anchor element so didn't pickup the styles for the top level anchor elements

```
.menubar button {
  float: none;
}
```